# Multiply Jquery Time Counter by database row query result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this javascript for displaying time counter :

```
$(function(){

        var note = $('.note'),
        ts = new Date(<?php echo $tgl_close1; ?>),
        newYear = true;

    if((new Date()) > ts){
        newYear = false;
    }

    $('.countdown').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
            var message = "";
            message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
            note.html(message);
        }
    });

});
```

i get the `$tgl_close` value from database. It working fine if i just call 1 row from my table, but i need to make a multiply time counter by the result of database query.

this is how my table looked :

```
id    |      tgl_close1     |   idrek
1     | 2014-11-25 08:00:00 |      1
2     | 2014-11-26 10:00:00 |      1
3     | 2014-11-26 12:10:00 |      1
```

i tried the stupid way by inserting the javascript into the `foreach` loop but it didn't work..
this is how i tried :

```
<?php 
$fetch = mysql_query("select tgl_close1
                      from tba
                      where idrek = 1");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $tgl_close1[] = date("Y, n-1, j, G, i, s", strtotime($row['tgl_close1']));


}
foreach ($tgl_close1 as $tglclose){
 ?>
<br>
    <table border="0"><tr><td>
    <div class="countdown"></div>
    <p class="note"></p>    
    </td></tr></table>

    <!-- JavaScript includes -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var note = $('.note'),
        ts = new Date(<?php echo $tgl_close; ?>),
        newYear = true;

    if((new Date()) > ts){
        newYear = false;
    }

    $('.countdown').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
            var message = "";
            message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
            message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
            note.html(message);
        }
    });

});

</script>
<?php
}
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Why foreach didn't work ? How did you do it ?

Comment: well i just simply put the `<script></script>` inside the foreach loop

Comment: Which jQuery countdown plugin are you using?

Comment: Do you have many countdown id ? If i'm right, you want to show multiple ts ? So you must have .countdown1, .countdowsn2 etc... ?

Comment: i used class instead of id because i want to show multiple time counter. but idk how to call the jquery as many as the row that i get from my query.

Comment: Can you add your html structure to the question or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: i've update my question with my html structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a place to test this and I'm not sure what you want your final html output to look like, but I think this should get you close:

```
<!-- JavaScript includes -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<?php 
$fetch = mysql_query("select tgl_close1
                      from tba
                      where idrek = 1");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<br>
<table border="0"><tr><td>
    <div class="countdown" data-ts="<?php echo date("r", strtotime($row['tgl_close1'])); ?>"></div>
    <p class="note"></p>    
</td></tr></table>


<?php
}
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('.countdown').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                ts = new Date($this.data('ts')),
                newYear = new Date() <= ts;
            $this.countdown({
                timestamp   : ts,
                callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                    var message = "";
                    message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                    message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                    message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                    message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                    $this.next().html(message);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: If you dump your generated html output into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) I'll try to debug it for you

Comment: sorry for late repply, I generated into pastebin in here [link](http://pastebin.com/Hv2MKcj3) but i can't make fiddle working for my code..

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until this morning, can you give me a link to the countdown plugin you are using? The generated html has a relative path in it so I can't test the actual script

Comment: I believe I found this issue, the date was being output in a format that the javascript couldn't parse. I've updated the answer so that it should output in the correct format now.